# How to change navigation item content and buttons, on tab bar click?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationitem

My code has a **Tab Bar Controller** and switches between **2 Scenes** with their own View Controllers.

The **Navigation Item on top** is the same on both, but I want to have different navigation item content, especially **the right button**.

I found a way to change the icon, with UITabBarControllerDelegate, but I need **different functionality** as well and connect those 2 different buttons, to those 2 Scenes.

Is there a solution? Thank you for your answers!